# Adding jQuery variable into placeholder in input field

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery multilanguage solution from https://github.com/coderkan/multi-language-jquery to add translation to a project I am working on which is working like it should, but I have an input field with a placeholder I also need to translate, but the "tools" in the JS does not give me a way out of the box to do so since I cannot place a `<span>` or similar into the `placeholder=""` attribute, so I need to find a solution on how I can do this.

The code:

What is "normally" used to add the translation in the HTML:

```
<span name="translate" caption="Need_Help"></span>
```

The INPUT field with placeholder ("Search.." is to be translated):

```
<input class="form-control" id="SearchEmployee" name="translate" caption="Search_Employee" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search..">
```

The jQuery:

```js
function getLangResources() {

    // Define arrays how many language you want to translate
    var da = new Array();
    var en = new Array();

    da['Need_Help'] = "Brug for hjælp?";
    en['Need_Help'] = "Need help?";

    // Added new array defined arrays.
    var resources = new Array();
    resources['da'] = da;
    resources['en'] = en;

    return resources;
}

function changeLanguage(lng) {
    var resources = getLangResources()[lng];

    $("h1[name='translate']").each(function(i, elt) {
        $(elt).text(resources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });
    $("h2[name='translate']").each(function(i, elt) {
        $(elt).text(resources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });
    $("h3[name='translate']").each(function(i, elt) {
        $(elt).text(resources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });
    $("span[name='translate']").each(function(i, elt) {
        $(elt).text(resources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });
    $("p[name='translate']").each(function(i, elt) {
        $(elt).text(resources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });
    $("button[name='translate']").each(function(i, elt) {
        $(elt).text(resources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });
    // This I have tried to deal with placeholder
    $("input[placeholder][name='translate']").each(function(i, elt) {
        $(elt).text(resources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });
}


$(function() {
    // Default Language
    changeLanguage("da");

    $("#da_button").click(function() {
        changeLanguage("da");
    });

    $("#eng_button").click(function() {
        changeLanguage("en");
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it like this. Try running the snippet, the code is runnable. Your problem is that your code uses the `.text(...)` function which sets the *inner text*, that is the contents between the opening and closening html tags, for a html emlement. To set a attribute of an html element, which placeholder is, you need to use the `.attr(...)` or `.prop(...)` functions.

https://api.jquery.com/attr/

https://api.jquery.com/prop/

```js
function getLangResources() {

    // Define arrays how many language you want to translate
    var da = new Array();
    var en = new Array();

    da['Need_Help'] = "Brug for hjælp?";
    en['Need_Help'] = "Need help?";
    
    da['Search_Employee'] = "søg efter en medarbejder";
    en['Search_Employee'] = "Search employee";

    // Added new array defined arrays.
    var resources = new Array();
    resources['da'] = da;
    resources['en'] = en;

    return resources;
}

function changeLanguage(lng) {
    var resources = getLangResources()[lng];

    $("h1[name='translate']").each(function(i, elt) {
        $(elt).text(resources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });
    $("h2[name='translate']").each(function(i, elt) {
        $(elt).text(resources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });
    $("h3[name='translate']").each(function(i, elt) {
        $(elt).text(resources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });
    $("span[name='translate']").each(function(i, elt) {
        $(elt).text(resources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });
    $("p[name='translate']").each(function(i, elt) {
        $(elt).text(resources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });
    $("button[name='translate']").each(function(i, elt) {
        $(elt).text(resources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });
    $("input[placeholder][name='translate']").each(function(i, elt) {
        $(elt).attr("placeholder", resources[$(elt).attr("caption")]);
    });
}


$(function() {
    // Default Language
    changeLanguage("da");

    $("#da_button").click(function() {
        changeLanguage("da");
    });

    $("#eng_button").click(function() {
        changeLanguage("en");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span name="translate" caption="Need_Help" /></span>
<input class="form-control" id="SearchEmployee" name="translate" caption="Search_Employee" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search.." />
```

Comment: Thank you @mortb, this was exactly what I was looking for perfect solution for me :-)

Comment: Bara glad att få hjälpa till :)

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a rework of your code, you're already not headed into a good direction.

Let's start with your `getLangResources()` function. The data structure it returns is basically a nested object, so let's skip all those tedious (and ill-applied) arrays:

```
function getLangResources() {
    return {
        Need_Help: {
            da: 'Brug for hjælp?',
            en: 'Need help?'
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose at some point this might return data from an HTTP request that fetches some JSON file, but for now let's keep it at returning a constant value.

```
const resources = getLangResources();
```

Next, your `changeLanguage()` function. It shows clear signs of copy-paste programming, so let's get rid of those first. Assume that each translatable element on your page has a CSS class called `translate`:

```
function changeLanguage(lng) {
    $(".translate").each(function () {
        $(this).text(resources[this.caption][lng]);
    });
}
```

This is better, but it still has drawbacks.

1. For one thing, it requires that the language resource ID is present in the `caption` attribute, and those are not standard HTML.
2. And for another thing, it will only replace the element's text. This is the issue you ask about.

So let's go one step further and address those

1. We could make a `data` attribute that contains the resource ID: `data-resource="Need_Help"`
2. We could make another data attribute that contains the property where this needs to go: `data-resource-target="text"`.

This would lead us to:

```
function changeLanguage(lng) {
    $(".translate").each(function () {
        var resourceId = $(this).data("resource");
        var resourceTarget = $(this).data("resource-target");
        $(this)[resourceTarget](resources[resourceId][lng]);
    });
}
```

That's better, since it allows us to choose e.g. `html` or `text` as the targets, which would enable basic HTML formatting such as bold in resource strings.

But it's still rather rigid

- It still does not allow setting e.g. an element's title
- It only allows setting *one* element property, not several.

So let's scrap that as well. What if we made up a format that allows defining multiple properties at once? I could imagine a list of id-target pairs could work:

```
data-lng="<resouce-id>:<resource-target>,<resouce-id>:<resource-target>,..."
```

We could name the targets according to HTML properties...

```
<a href="..." class="translate" data-lng="Need_Help:textContent,Further_Information:title"></a>
```

...and set them directly on the element itself, instead of going through jQuery.

```
function changeLanguage(lng) {
    $(".translate").each(function () {
        var lng = $(this).data("lng");
        for (let pair of lng.split(',')) {
            let [resourceId, target] of pair.split(':');
            this[target] = resources[resourceId][lng];
        }
    });
}
```

Now you can target the `placeholder` just as easily as everything else.

---

Going from there you could go on and define convenience shorthands, things like

- if there only is a single item (i.e. not a pair) in the lng attribute, assume it's meant to target the element's `textContent`: `data-lng="Need_Help"`
- Maybe you want to define a shorthand for the property name `textContent`, such as `.`: `data-lng="Need_Help:.,Further_Information:title"`

It's up to you, whatever you find practical.

Comment: Thank you @Tomalak, that was a very nice answer, and I will definently dig into this .. the reason I do not mark this as the answer is because it will not fix the project right now, I need some time to play with it .. the solution from mortb on the other hand fixed it right now .. thank you for your time :-)

Comment: @StigKølbæk Your current approach is unsustainable. If you keep spending time to tack on band-aids, you will never fix it.

Comment: @StigKølbæk ...but generally speaking, it's a nice exercise to create a translation framework from scratch. It can teach you a lot about how the DOM works and how to do things e.g. with or without jQuery. But internationalization is a solved problem, there is more than one battle-tested framework to pick from. In the medium run, I'd recommend choosing an existing translation framework and use that, instead of rolling your own.

Comment: You are absolutely right @Tomalak, and I will definently use your approach at a much larger project I am working on, for this small project I have only 4 slides with 26 labels, and a deadline to meet, so that is why I for this project choose the easy fix, but for the larger I am also working on I have 1000+ labels, and it needs translated to alot more languages, so when I start that translation project I will be using your approaches, and as you write find a existing translation framework :-) .. btw, the solution used here is from https://github.com/coderkan/multi-language-jquery not my code.

Comment: @StigKølbæk Yes, that is completely horrible code, I can only recommend *not* to use it. Not everything that is on Github is actually worth considering.